# Account Owner field shouldn't get updated when my batch runs

Tags: apex, batch

I have designed a batch on Accounts that would trigger whenever there is a change of field called "Sales_Rep__c" on object "Sales_Territory_Mapping__c". For my batch I have a scenario where I have a checkbox on Account called "KRM". If this KRM is checked the batch should run and include the account but shouldn't update owner name. How can I achieve it.

```
global class salesRepProcessingBatch_Accounts implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{
    set<String> soldInTerrBatch = new set<String>();  
    List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c > accountList = new List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c >(); 



    global salesRepProcessingBatch_Accounts (set<String> soldInTerrBatchRet , List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c > accountTerrList)
    {   
        soldInTerrBatch =soldInTerrBatchRet ;        
        accountList = accountTerrList;
        system.debug('Updating global class accountList '+ accountList.size());
        system.debug('Updating global class accountList123456 '+ accountList.size());
        system.debug('Territory Id'+soldInTerrBatch);
        system.debug('Territory Id'+soldInTerrBatchRet );
    }

    //Start Method
    global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    system.debug('before query ');
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Name, TerritoryId__c, Sales_Rep_CS_ID__c,Sales_Rep_M_ID__c,ISAL_CS_ID__c,ISAL_M_ID__c FROM Account WHERE TerritoryId__c In: soldInTerrBatch and KRM_Program__c =false');//Query which will be determine the scope of Records fetching the same
        //system.debug('after query ');
    }

    //Execute method
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> scope) {
    system.debug('execute ');
        List<Account> customerList = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> updtaedsalesRepList = new List<Account>();//List to hold updated customer
        if(!accountList.isEmpty())
        {
        system.debug('accountList '+accountList);
            for(Sales_Territory_Mapping__c salesTer : accountList)
            {
                for (sObject objScope: scope) { 
                    Account newObjScope = (Account)objScope ;//type casting from generic sOject to Shipping_Address__c 
                    if(salesTer.Role__c=='ISALM')
                    {    

                        newObjScope.ISAL_M_ID__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;                                                       
                    }
                    if(salesTer.Role__c=='FSALM')
                    {                        
                        //newObjScope.TerritoryNames__c='Updated Via FSALM Batch Job'; 
                        newObjScope.Sales_Rep_M_ID__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;
                        newObjScope.AccTerritoryNameM__c = salesTer.SalesTerrMapName__c;       
                    }
                    if(salesTer.Role__c=='FSALCS')
                    {    
                     System.debug('FSALCS');                   
                        newObjScope.Sales_Rep_CS_ID__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;
                        newObjScope.AccTerritoryNameCS__c = salesTer.SalesTerrMapName__c;          
                    }
                    if(salesTer.Role__c=='ISALCS')
                    {                        
                        newObjScope.ISAL_CS_ID__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;    
                    }
                    updtaedsalesRepList.add(newObjScope);//Add records to the List
                    System.debug('Value of updtaedsalesRepList '+updtaedsalesRepList);
                } 
            }
            if (updtaedsalesRepList != null && updtaedsalesRepList.size()>0) {//Check if List is empty or not
                Database.update(updtaedsalesRepList); 
                System.debug('List Size '+updtaedsalesRepList.size());//Update the Records
            }
        }       
    }

    //Finish Method
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){  
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
    Public class SalesRepMapping_Accounts{

Public static void updateSalesRepMapping(List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c> salesList, Map<Id,Sales_Territory_Mapping__c> salesNewMap, Map<Id, Sales_Territory_Mapping__c> salesOldMap){
system.debug('entering to the class');
List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c> AccTerr = new List <Sales_Territory_Mapping__c>();
List<Account> AccList = new List <Account>();
List<Account> finalAccList = new List <Account>();
Set<String> soldinTerr = new set<String>();

for(Sales_Territory_Mapping__c st: salesList){
if(st.SoldInTerritoryId__c != Null && salesOldMap.get(st.id).Sales_Rep__c != salesNewMap.get(st.id).Sales_Rep__c){
//soldinTerr.add(st.SoldInTerritoryId__c);
soldinTerr.add(st.SoldinTerritory_Name__c);
//soldinTerr.add(st.name);
AccTerr.add(st);
system.debug('soldInTerName'+soldinTerr);
system.debug('AccTerr'+AccTerr);

        system.debug('Account>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Sales_Territory_Mapping__c soldInTerr'+soldInTerr);
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Sales_Territory_Mapping__c AccTerr'+AccTerr);

Database.ExecuteBatch(new salesRepProcessingBatch_Accounts(soldInTerr,AccTerr));

}
}

}
}
```

Comment: On a quick glance nothing in your code seems to be changing the OwnerId. Do you have some other code that sets the owner based on the value of any of the fields you are changing

Comment: It's the other Apex Class that calls this batch has OwnerID. I have added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to NOT update accounts with the KRM checked add this to your execute method int he for loop:

```
for (sObject objScope: scope) { 
    Account newObjScope = (Account)objScope ;//type casting from generic sOject to Shipping_Address__c 

    If(newObjScope.KRM__c == true) continue;
    //..........//
}
```

It will not process that record.

or if you need it to process but not update (Not sure what that would serve)

```
for (sObject objScope: scope) { 
    Account newObjScope = (Account)objScope ;//type casting from generic sOject to Shipping_Address__c 
    //..........//                      
    If(newObjScope.KRM__c == false) updtaedsalesRepList.add(newObjScope);//Add records to the List;
}
```

And you can remove the check for empty or null (it won't be null since you explicitly declared it

```
if (updtaedsalesRepList != null && updtaedsalesRepList.size()>0)
```

as it will not consume a DML or rows if the list is empty

Per your comment below you said you want to process but not update the Owner field. You are not setting it anywhere in the code you presented so the following is the best I can do

As a general concept though

Since you may have a helper class that does the modification of the OwnerIds and you have a single instance where you do not want this to happen, the easiest way to refactor this without affecting other units of work would be to use a static property to short circuit:

```
Public class xyz_class{

      public static stopMe = false;

      Public static void xyz_method(){

             if(stopMe) return;

       }


}
```

Then in your batch:

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> scope) {

     xyz_class.stopMe = true;

     //.............//

}
```

If the class that calls your batch is modifying the OwnerId, simply **dont do that**

Unfortunately, your question is unclear and leads to many other questions...

Comment: I want the process to update and include the account with KRM == true but I just do not want one field to update. The field is Account Owner on the Account object.

Comment: @SFDCLearner - Then don't set the value of the field. I do not see anywhere you are doing that so i have **NO IDEA** what to tell you. There is most likely a process setting that value when you perform the update. You need to FIND IT and modify it. I updated my answer to show you how to refactor to do so